Entry point not found while my DLL file is in a folder next to my EXE
I have my EXE file compiled by Visual Studio. I am coding in C++ and I can debug and run my code correctly with the correct additional dependencies and working directory.
I would get this error:

The procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library

I get that it could not find the main function of the DLL file leading to this, meaning my EXE could not find the DLL file. The problem is, I had this error before in Visual Studio and I set the working directory to OutDir which fixed it, but the standalone EXE file would still give the error.
I have used LoadLibrary() and I do not understand why it doesn't work, it should find the path.
Note: my DLL is the correct version, latest update, is the required format, and located in a folder named [binary] which is next to my EXE.
#define NOMINMAX


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sfml/graphics.hpp>



static void DLLErrorHandler(HMODULE& DLL1, HMODULE& DLL2, HMODULE& DLL3, HMODULE& DLL4, HMODULE& DLL5, HMODULE& DLL6) {
    DLL1 = LoadLibrary(L".\\binary\\openal32.dll");
    DLL2 = LoadLibrary(L".\\binary\\sfml-audio-d-2.dll");
    DLL3 = LoadLibrary(L".\\binary\\sfml-graphics-d-2.dll");
    DLL4 = LoadLibrary(L".\\binary\\sfml-network-d-2.dll");
    DLL5 = LoadLibrary(L".\\binary\\sfml-system-d-2.dll");
    DLL6 = LoadLibrary(L".\\binary\\sfml-window-d-2.dll");

    switch (0) {
        case 0:
            if (DLL1 == NULL) MessageBox(NULL, L"Missing DLL: openai32.dll", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
        case 1:
            if (DLL2 == NULL) MessageBox(NULL, L"Missing DLL: sfml-audio-d-2.dll", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
        case 2:
            if (DLL3 == NULL) MessageBox(NULL, L"Missing DLL: sfml-graphics-d-2.dll", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
        case 3:
            if (DLL4 == NULL) MessageBox(NULL, L"Missing DLL: sfml-network-d-2.dll", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
        case 4:
            if (DLL5 == NULL) MessageBox(NULL, L"Missing DLL: sfml-system-d-2.dll", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
        case 5:
            if (DLL6 == NULL) MessageBox(NULL, L"Missing DLL: sfml-window-d-2.dll", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
        default:
            if (DLL1 != NULL && DLL2 != NULL && DLL3 != NULL && DLL4 != NULL && DLL5 != NULL && DLL6 != NULL){
                std::cout << "DLL files loaded!";
            }
            else {
                exit(1);
            }
    }
}

static void DLLrelease(HMODULE& DLL1, HMODULE& DLL2, HMODULE& DLL3, HMODULE& DLL4, HMODULE& DLL5, HMODULE& DLL6) {
    FreeLibrary(DLL1);
    FreeLibrary(DLL2);
    FreeLibrary(DLL3);
    FreeLibrary(DLL4);
    FreeLibrary(DLL5);
    FreeLibrary(DLL6);
}


int main() {
    HMODULE DLL1, DLL2, DLL3, DLL4, DLL5, DLL6;
    DLLErrorHandler(DLL1, DLL2, DLL3, DLL4, DLL5, DLL6);

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML Window");
    sf::CircleShape bicycle(20.f);
    bicycle.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
    bicycle.setPosition(400.f, 300.f);

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed) {
                if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left) {
                    sf::Vector2i mousePosition = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
                    bicycle.setPosition(static_cast<float>(mousePosition.x), static_cast<float>(mousePosition.y));
                }
            }
        }

        // Clear window
        window.clear(sf::Color::White);

        // Draw objects
        window.draw(bicycle);

        // Display window contents
        window.display();
    }

    DLLrelease(DLL1, DLL2, DLL3, DLL4, DLL5, DLL6);
    return 0;
}

I have done correct linkage and everything, all run smoothly on Visual Studio when debugging mode in x64, but when I double-click my standalone EXE it says "entry point not found", which I do not know what to do.
I would like my DLL to stay in the folder and not be located next to my EXE file, and I want my EXE to recognize that my DLL files are in the [binary] folder next to it and do not need to add to the system PATH because if I want to distribute it, it would not work.
Note: I am new to DLL files and linkage and stuff, so I would really want to learn dynamically linking, static link would not be preferred, but any education from you guys would be appreciated.
Note: This is the message from depends.exe:
Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: A circular dependency was detected.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

This is my file structure:
FpsKing/
│
├── FpsKing.exe
│
└── binary/
    ├── openal32.dll
    ├── sfml-audio-d-2.dll
    ├── sfml-graphics-d-2.dll
    ├── sfml-network-d-2.dll
    ├── sfml-system-d-2.dll
    └── sfml-window-d-2.dll



L".\\binary\\openal32.dll", L"Missing DLL: openai32.dll" - you have a typo.

Be careful when using relative paths. The working directory might  not be what you expect.

So what should I do to resolve it?

Well, first off, your project is setup incorrectly, because the EXE is looking for an imported function inside of itself instead of from a DLL.
As for the DLLs themselves - when you static link to a DLL, the OS loader looks for the DLL at program startup in the EXE's folder, in the system PATH, in the KnownDLLs Registry key, etc (see Dynamic-link library search order). In your case, your DLLs are in none of those places, so a static link will fail at runtime.  You can't statically load a DLL from a subfolder unless it is in the system PATH or Registry, etc.
For what you are attempting, you need to dynamically load the DLLs instead, via LoadLibrary() or your linker's delay-load feature (if it has one).
Then, in your code, do not use relative paths at all.  Use absolute paths instead. Have your EXE retrieve its own absolute path via GetModuleFileName(), strip off the .exe filename from the end, and append the binary subfolder. Now you have a base folder from which you can load your DLLs from.
If you use delay-loading, you can pass the base folder to SetDllDirectory() or AddDllDirectory() before calling any delay-loaded DLL function.
Otherwise, you can pass the base folder directly to LoadLibrary() when loading each DLL yourself, eg:
#define NOMINMAX

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
#include <windows.h>
...

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

static fs::path getDllFolderPath()
{
    WCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH] = {};
    if (GetModuleFileNameW(nullptr, szPath, MAX_PATH)) {
        return fs::path(szPath).remove_filename().append("binary");
    }
    return L""; // or throw...
}

static HINSTANCE LoadDLL(const std::wstring &filename) {
    static fs::path dllFolder = getDllFolderPath();
    HINSTANCE hDll = LoadLibraryW((dllFolder / filename).c_str());
    if (!hDll) {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, (L"Can't load DLL: " + filename).c_str(), L"Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    }
    return hDll;
}

static void DLLErrorHandler(HMODULE& DLL1, HMODULE& DLL2, HMODULE& DLL3, HMODULE& DLL4, HMODULE& DLL5, HMODULE& DLL6) {
    DLL1 = LoadDLL(L"openal32.dll");
    DLL2 = LoadDLL(L"sfml-audio-d-2.dll");
    DLL3 = LoadDLL(L"sfml-graphics-d-2.dll");
    DLL4 = LoadDLL(L"sfml-network-d-2.dll");
    DLL5 = LoadDLL(L"sfml-system-d-2.dll");
    DLL6 = LoadDLL(L"sfml-window-d-2.dll");

    if (DLL1 && DLL2 && DLL3 && DLL4 && DLL5 && DLL6) {
        std::cout << "DLL files loaded!\n";
    }
    else {
        exit(1);
    }
}

static void DLLrelease(HMODULE& DLL1, HMODULE& DLL2, HMODULE& DLL3, HMODULE& DLL4, HMODULE& DLL5, HMODULE& DLL6) {
    FreeLibrary(DLL1);
    FreeLibrary(DLL2);
    FreeLibrary(DLL3);
    FreeLibrary(DLL4);
    FreeLibrary(DLL5);
    FreeLibrary(DLL6);
}

int main() {
    HMODULE DLL1, DLL2, DLL3, DLL4, DLL5, DLL6;
    DLLErrorHandler(DLL1, DLL2, DLL3, DLL4, DLL5, DLL6);

    ...

    DLLrelease(DLL1, DLL2, DLL3, DLL4, DLL5, DLL6);
    return 0;
}


Wait so how can I tell my exe to dynamically load it instead of statically

By NOT linking to the DLL's lib file at compile time (unless you use delay loading). Use LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress() at runtime. See Run-Time Dynamic Linking and Using Run-Time Dynamic Linking.
